# Does there have to be a body to the init method in python?

Tags: python

Am I allowed to not put any parameters besides self into the init method? Can I also have a body  that does not define any other variables besides self?

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self = self
```

Or do I have to put a parameter and a body like so:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Comment: You can use a `pass`.

Comment: Why define an `__init__` if it doesn't do anything?

Comment: `self = self` doesn't do anything useful

Comment: Defining an `__init__()` method is optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have nothing to initialize, than you don't need to define an `__init__` method at all.  Just don't define it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `__init__`, then there is no reason to define it at all. 
*However,* if this is theoretical, then ***I*** have a question for you: Why don't **you** try it first?

For the sake of completion, here is my trial:

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self = self
... 
>>> foo()
<__main__.foo object at 0x1004afa50>
>>> x = foo()
>>>
```

So an answer: **yes you can do this.**

<sup>Just a point, instead of calling `self = self`, just put `pass`; it was built to be a placeholder in situations like this.</sup>